# the Location Service not working with UIWebView in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My app has an UIWebView to use Location Service via HTML5.  It works fine below iOS 10. When you first launch the app, and get to the webView, then an alert appears to ask use's allowance of system Location Service. Under your permission, the UIWebView does it's work. Everything feels awesome.

However, when I installed my app to an device running iOS10, the alert doesn't show up. And the UIWebView shows an error. I even cannot find location settings in the Settings app.

Does any body get the same problem? Or could anyone tell me what happened? Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: I faced same issue. if you are using http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true then change to **https**. It will work.

Comment: Make sure you have location enabled for safari browser in Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Safari

Comment: @MihirOza Yeah, you're right.  Although I've solved this problem, thank U all the same. And I use the Baidu map service. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find anything specific to UIWebView, however, I have seen that apple is now blocking calls to the geolocation API on insecure pages.

> Web APIs
>
> Started blocking Geolocation API calls on pages served over insecure
>   connections

[See release notes](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/)

I suspect your problem is related to this.

Comment: But, what does Apple mean with "insecure connections"?  Did that mean we have to  use https instead of http? Any idea?

Comment: @Neal.Marlin yes, you will have to use https

Comment: thks for your help and I'll try it out.

Comment: @Neal.Marlin please let as know if you did it and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you forget add Privacy keys in your app's info.plist.

you can find the infomation in the iOS10 update's Guide.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've configured my app with "When In Use" description. This configuration change begins with iOS 8, but my app work fine below iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

The webview will start monitoring the location automatically, however since iOS 8 location access requires the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription description in your info plist to be set.

If this has been done, it will prompt the user automatically to allow location access.

Comment: I've done that "When In Use" configuration and it surely works as you say below iOS 10.  It goes wrong only in iOS 10!